# How can I convert object to integer from the dataframe in Python with contains colon(:) and space?

Tags: python, string, object, integer

Data contains colon(:) and also space, so all the columns type is object. How can I convert to all columns object to integer or float.

I try this, but its not working.

```
df = pd.concat([df[col].str.split()
                       .str[0]
                       .str.replace(':','').astype(float) for col in df], axis=1)
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(int)
print(df)
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to extract the numbers, then convert it to integer afterwards. See the code below:

```py
import re

def to_integer(x):
    result = re.findall('[0-9]+', str(x))
    num = ''.join(result)
    return int(num)

df['col'] = df['col'].apply(to_integer)
```